# How to check if session exists or not?

Tags: java, session, servlets

I am creating the session using

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
```

Before creating session I want to check if it exists or not. How would I do this?

Answer (score 41):

If you want to check this *before* creating, then do so:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if (session == null) {
    // Not created yet. Now do so yourself.
    session = request.getSession();
} else {
    // Already created.
}
```

If you don't care about checking this *after* creating, then you can also do so:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
if (session.isNew()) {
    // Freshly created.
} else {
    // Already created.
}
```

That saves a line and a `boolean`. The [`request.getSession()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29) does the same as [`request.getSession(true)`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29).

Answer (score 23):

There is a function [`request.getSession(boolean create)`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28boolean%29)

> **Parameters:**
>       `create` - true to create a new session for this request if necessary; false to return null if there's no current session

Thus, you can simply pass `false` to tell the `getSession` to return null if the session does not exist.

Comment: ...best explaination imho... refers to docs and keeps focused.

Answer (score 6):

```
if(null == session.getAttribute("name")){  
  // User is not logged in.  
}else{  
  // User IS logged in.  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
if (session.isNew()) {
  ...do something
} else {
  ...do something else
}
```

the `.getSession(true)` tells java to create a new session if none exists.

you might of course also do:

```
if(request.getSession(false) != null){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
}
```

have a look at: [HttpServletRequest.html](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html)

cheers,
Jørgen

Comment: You would have to pass `false` to the second `.getSession()`.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to add that if you create a new session for every new user connecting to your website then your performance will take a hard hit. Use request.getSession(false) to check if a user has a session. With this method you don't create a new session if you're going to render a view based on if a user is authenticated or not.