# If session exist or not

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jsp, session

I am trying to write my first app on `Google App Engine`, I was trying to maintain a session, I created a login page on submit, it call to a `servlet`, servlet validates the user and create a new session using the following code.

```
void createSession(String Username) {
        getThreadLocalRequest().getSession(true).setAttribute("Username", Username);
    }
```

login page after calling the servlet redirects to some page i.e. `abc.jsp`, my `abc.jsp` page contains

```
<body><%
        try {
            if (request.getSession(false) == null) {

            } else {
    %>
    Welcome to
    <%=session.getAttribute("Username")%>
    <%
        if (session.getAttribute("Username").equals("")) {
    %>
    <a href="login.jsp"><b>Login </b></a>
    <%
        } else {
    %>
    <a href="logout.jsp"><b>Logout</b></a>
    <%
        }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    %></body>
```

it works fine, but when I access `abc.jsp` **without** creating a session it is throwing an exception at this `if (session.getAttribute("Username").equals(""))` line,  I dunno why kindly help me. I think it dont detect if session exists. but I have read so many threads like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818251/how-to-check-if-session-exists-or-not) It gave me this solution, I dunno what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I remember

```
session.getAttribute("xyz")
```

returns `null` if the attribute does not exist...
so your NullPointerException occurs because you try to call `equals` on `null`.

I suggest to do a check on your attribute itself before validating its content:

```
if (session.getAttribute("Username") == null || session.getAttribute("Username").equals(""))
```

Comment: thanx that worked, but this is telling me a different story >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818251/how-to-check-if-session-exists-or-not << I was thinking if there is no harm in using that code ?

Comment: Well .. a session-Object is automatically created when a user requests a site on your server even if you do not call `getSession(<boolean>)` manually. But of course this "default-session" is empty, meaning it has no attributes, so `getAttribute(<String>)` returns `null`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <%  
     if (session.getAttribute("Username") != null) {  
         …
     }
  %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Before to check session's attributes, you have to see the session itself.

So, **first**:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null){...}
```

and **then**,

```
if(session.getAttribute("xyz") != null){...}
```

**Better solution** might be **both in one line**:

```
if(session != null && session.getAttribute("xyz") != null)
```

> returns null if the attribute does not exist... so your
>   NullPointerException occurs because you try to call equals on null.

Obviously, it's **strictly recommended** to **check your attribute**, before validating its content (as above).

Answer (score 0):

It Worked For me. Try This

```
String userName;
    userName = (String)session.getAttribute("uname");   
if (session.getAttribute("userName").equals(""))
```