# httpsession verification if exists

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

**strong text**I am new, need a proper way to validate. I followed

5 line code.  it doent have a httpsession but still going to appointment.jsp . why so?
I followed [How to check if session exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818251/how-to-check-if-session-exists-or-not)

it is giving a session. org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@3b59e880  but the user is not login in...

it does. but I dont know why and how it got one?

```
if (request.getSession(false) == null) {
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
} else if (request.getSession(false) != null) {
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/appointment.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Session is not created after your user logs in, It is created at the first request to the container from a browser. This enables container to track subsequent requests from same browser. This is implemented usually using a cookie with unique id(session id).

So even it depends on what is happening at user logout? are you calling session.invalidate(). 
We cant say a user as authenticated just because session object is not null.

Comment: why. If create is false and the request has no valid HttpSession, this method returns null.   (isnt this proper way?
)

Comment: HttpSession getSession()
Returns the current session associated with this request, or if the request does not have a session, creates one.

Comment: yes, let me know if your authenitcation is done using a custom logic(say filter)?

Comment: you mean even if i make a session or not. the browser makes an implicit session when the use opens the page? and its best to make a session attribute like "session exists" "yes"/"no"

Comment: yes , it is always best to set a "IS_AUTHENTICATED" boolean flag in session attribute.such that it is set to true on login, and if that is not set or false means login page. Another best way is to your session tracking in a filter, with your custom logic which will give you flexibilities like  tracking each session in database or forcefully logout a user session etc

Comment: if ((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn")){   would be ok?

Comment: just handle the Null pointer also request.getSession(false) could be null, request.getSession(false).getAttribute("name") could be null

Comment: thanks. now I have all questions that are fit for an answer but i have to choose one.

Comment: still getting exceptions . pastebin.ca/2297351

Comment: Please check what is causing the nullpointer in Appointment.java:67 th line

Comment: that id the doget method. and comes from line 38.  if ((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") != null

Comment: just add `request.getSession(false)!=null ` also

Comment: I do have implicit session made by browser too.

Comment: Thanks alot. plus one. but still theres not workable code for problem avoidance of null pointer exception with implicit sessions of browsers. how about i change it to int instead of boolean?

Comment: this works. if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") != null ){ if((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") ){ request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/appointment.jsp").forward(req‌​uest, response); } }else { request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response); }

Answer (score 1):

There will always be a HttpSession object (ok, not always, but most of the time) - this is not an indicator for an authenticated user.

You need to set a session attribute eg. "authenticated" to flag this session as authenticated or not.

You can add this by calling request.getSession().setAttribute(...)

Comment: if ((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn")){  is ok?

Comment: yes, except for the potential NPEs. (getSesstion can return null, getAttribute can also return null aaand request can also be null)

Comment: is this ok?  if ((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn")){
                       
               out.println("there is  session");
                out.print(request.getSession(false));
         
            }else if (!(Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") ||
                    (Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") == null){
               
               out.println("there is no session");
               out.print(request.getSession(false));

Comment: well, the style is not ok. But i think you will achieve what you plan, with that.

Comment: (Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") can be null. Boolean loggedIn = (Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn"); Then check if loggedIn is null or not.

Comment: if ( session != null ) {            // no no. I also have an implicit session made by browser.

Comment: yeah, correct. but the method signature CAN return null, that is why you need to check it.

Comment: Thanks alot. plus one. but still theres not workable code for problem avoidance of null pointer exception with implicit sessions of browsers

Comment: how about i change it to int instead of boolean?

Comment: this works. if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") != null ){ if((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") ){ request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/appointment.jsp").forward(req‌​uest, response); } }else { request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response); }

Answer (score 1):

By default, a JSP will create a session. You probably don't want that behavior for your login page, so use the page directive in `login.jsp`:

```
<%@ page session="false" %>
```

You would also need to make sure that any other JSP that is accessed before a successful login does not create a session.

Comment: thanks. now I have all questions that are fit for an answer but i have to choose one.

Comment: I have made session = "false"  but still i get an implicit session

Comment: Make sure none of your other pages are creating sessions prior to successful login and, as mentioned in one of the other answers, make sure to invalidate the current session when the user logs out.

Comment: Thanks alot. plus one Thanks alot. plus one. but still theres not workable code for problem avoidance of null pointer exception with implicit sessions of browsers

Comment: this works. if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") != null ){
                if((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") ){
                    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/appointment.jsp").forward(request, response);
                }
                
            }else {
                request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
            }

Comment: There is no such thing as "implicit sessions of browsers". The session has to be created by your application. For JSP, the default is to create a session, but this is still done within the scope of your app, not the browser.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") != null ) {
    if((Boolean)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn") ) {
        request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/appointment.jsp").forward(request, response);
    }
} else {
    request.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/login.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

Comment: Just so you're aware, you're leaving yourself open to a `NullPointerException` by doing: `request.getSession(false).getAttribute("userLoggedIn")` because `getSession(false)` can return `null`.

Comment: @kschneid so what should be done? wrap another if() to check session is not null? can you tell how? . well if the session isnt there so userLoggedIn will be null.  the code then comes to else{} block. so no issues?