# Java session deleted after page refresh

Tags: java, jsp, session, request

I have a web site where I have a login form. If the login is successfull I put the object user into the session and I go in another page (in which I need the session attributes) in this way:

-Java Servlet-

```
 request.getSession(true).setAttribute("utente", u);
 request.getSession(true).setAttribute("abbonamento", a);
 request.getRequestDispatcher("HomeUtente.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

-Jsp page-

```
    <%
    Utente u = null;
    Abbonamento a = null;
    try {
        u = (Utente) session.getAttribute("utente");
        a = (Abbonamento) session.getAttribute("abbonamento");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        a = null;
        u = null;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
%>
```

Now, If I do this once it's ok, but If I refresh the page it seems that the session will be deleted.

I guess this because when I refresh the page (in debug mode) a and u will be both null.

Any idea?

Comment: How are confirming that the session is deleted?

Comment: @BheshGurung   I guess this because when I refresh the page (in debug mode) a and u will be both null.

Comment: Post full code of your servlet and JSP to get some clue.

Answer (score -1):

Java Session -

`HttpSession getSession(boolean create)`  -

Returns the current HttpSession associated with this request or, if there is no current session and create is true, returns a new session.

So in your program as you are using -

`request.getSession(true)` -

it is always returning a new session and previous session variables are deleted.

also you can view the following link for better understanding -

[How to check if session exists or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818251/how-to-check-if-session-exists-or-not)

Comment: The session is only created if a session does not exist. The OP does not delete/invalidate the session so there is nt reason for `request.getSession(true)` recreate the session.