# onbeforeunload works also with refreshing

Tags: javascript, ajax, refresh, onbeforeunload, page-refresh

I did this question few days ago ([Java session deleted after page refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15326562/java-session-deleted-after-page-refresh)) and I didn't have an answer. Maybe because the problem was in the onbeforeunload event. 
with:

```
 <body onbeforeunload="chiudi()">
```

I would like to rifle the session. The problem is that in this way the session will be
rifled also if the user refresh the page. How can I fix it?

Here's my javascript function chiudi()

```
 function chiudi(){
 var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "SvuotaSession", false);
    xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type",
            "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlHttp.send(null);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can.  You aren't allowed to get information about where the user is going to  (according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1686687/how-can-i-get-the-destination-url-in-javascript-onbeforeunload-event)), so there isn't a way to know that the user is refreshing the current page.

Comment: :-( If the user close the page does the session rifle itself?

Comment: If by "rifle" you mean the session ends, that depends on the server side technology.  ASP.NET will end the session eventually based on the timeout.  Not sure what serverside tech you are using.